# C# Expression Tree NULL check

Tags: c#, lambda

I am trying to write an expression tree that determines if the value of a property of an incoming object is null. This code works fine when value.{property} is not null, but when it IS null, I get a NullReferenceException

```
var valueAsType = Expression.Convert(value, type);            
var property = Expression.Property(valueAsType, type, propertyInfo.Name);
var isNotNullCondition = Expression.NotEqual(property, Expression.Constant(null, propertyInfo.PropertyType));
```

The Debug view of the condition seems to make sense too:

```
((ProperyValiationLambda.SetEmptyToNullTest)$value).Value != null
```

Comment: Is it possible your failure is not when `{value}.{property}` is null, but when `{value}` is null?